# IBM MQ MQQueueManager & connection pooling

Tags: java, ibm-mq, connection-pooling

I am integration with IBM MQ from inside web service, java web service. I'm a bit unsure if I should create one instance of MQQueueManager per thread or have a single instance for all request threads ? Is MQQueueManager  thread safe ? I "think" an instance of MQQueueManager represents one connection to MQ.

Also should I configure my own connection pool or use the default ... Is there any difference between the default pool vs configuring a

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html It is synchronized and thread safe. As far as connection pooling goes, this only creates one connection to the WebSphere MQ. One thread can access it at a time, hopefully a thread can facilitate the "connections" you had in mind. This means each thread (e.g. user request) can access it threadsafe

Comment: While I can use one instance for all request / user request thread I guess its better to have one per thread instead ? So this would be similar to JMS where a single session is created per request.

Comment: I would say it's best to have one connection used by all user requests. I'm referring to a REST API request from a user, where each request accesses the same connection. This should be okay to use as a singleton in that case, as creating a new connection (or MQ connection reference) for each request is kind of an overload, and would have it's own performance implications. Maybe a good balance would be that you could do the pooling yourself maybe. Suppose you had 5 connections opened (5 MQQueueManager references) ready to load-balance all requests, that should cover most basic cases for you.